# Ajuda com jdbctemplate / query / rs

Tags: spring

Bom estou tentando dar um select no banco de dados para pegar os dados a partir de uma String:

```
final String queryPorLogin = "SELECT * from usuarios where login=? ";
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public boolean validar(String login) {
    return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(queryPorLogin, new Usuarios(), 
    login);
}
```

mas estou com esse error:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

creio que não seja a query correta para se utilizar nesse caso
por que eu quero fazer um select no banco de dados e caso exista um resultado utilizar o resultset para fazer uma verificação ( das senhas com bcrpyt )alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Alguma razão para não configurar um `AuthenticationManager` utilizando Spring Security?

Comment: @nullptr não sabia da existencia do mesmo, mas eu já consegui resolver esse metodo ( vou procurar saber para o que server )

Comment: seria interessante para a comunidade se você respondesse sua própria questão ao conseguir resolver o problema, sua resposta pode contribuir para resolver o problema de outras pessoas no futuro

Comment: @nullptr opa eu não sabia que tinha essa possíbilidade vou responder agora.

Comment: @nullptr pronto mano, eu não sabia que existia essa possibilidade, se você poder dar uma averiguada e ver onde posso melhorar .

Answer (score 0):

Bom depois de muita busca sobre o tema acabei chegando a esse metodo:

```
public boolean verificar(String login, String senha) {
    try {
    Usuarios usuarios = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(queryPorLogin, new Object[]{login}, 
    new RowMapper<Usuarios>() { 
    public Usuarios mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException { 
    Usuarios user = new Usuarios();
    if(BCrypt.checkpw(senha, rs.getString("senha"))) {
        user.setIdUsuario(rs.getLong("idUsuario"));
        user.setLogin(rs.getString("login"));
        user.setSenha(rs.getString("senha"));
    }
    return user;
    } 
    });
        if(usuarios.getIdUsuario() != null) {
        System.out.println(usuarios.toString()); 
        return true;
        }else {
        return false;
        }
    }catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("Senha errada");
        return false;
    }
}
```

eu primeiro faço o select no banco de dados, e caso a senha encryptada com bcrypt seja igual a senha digitada eu vou setar o usuario e depois fazer uma verificação se o id do usuario é diferente de nulo ( se for retorna um true, que vou utilizar no meu controller)

catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("Senha errada");
        return false;
    }

o catch eu procurei bastante, pois antes não estava utilizando o try catch e quando não tinha um resultado gerava um joptionpane do error.

Caso alguém possa me ajudar onde melhorar no codigo ficaria grato!